What is the way to set LWC (Lightning debug mode) with an 'sf cli' command for the admin User if it exists?
Use case:
I want to assign to the admin user of my newly created scratch org the 'Debug Mode' so that when I open my new scratch to be able to directly start debugging my LWC components. Is that possible?
Additional information:
I want to automate my scratch org creation by using npm run * commands.
I use:

sf org create scratch --edition developer -c -a features-scratch --track-source to create the scratch
sf config set target-org features-scratch to set the default org
sf project deploy validate --source-dir force-app to deploy source
sf org assign permset --name MyPS --target-org features-scratch to assign additional permissions for my components and test apps

(Note: I am using '-c' flag to avoid package deployment.)

You could automate this with something like:
sf data update record --sobject User --where "Name='User User'" --values "UserPreferencesUserDebugModePref=true"

Change the query filter as appropriate.
